# Getting strange error in NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary

I am getting strange exception when calling the NSDictionary in the following example:

```
NSInteger userId = 1;
NSDictionary *postData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      @"3", @"a",
                      @"0", @"b",
                      userId, @"c",
                      nil];
```

Can someone see what's the problem above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSDictionary`, as most collections, just accepts real Obj-C objects (`id` type), but you are passing a `NSInteger` which is a normal C typedef.

Try with `NSNumber userId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];`